# Conectar a un SGDB de SQL Microsoft SQL Server 12 con PHP 7.4

Tags: php, ubuntu, sql-server-2012, odbc, sqlsrv

Necesitaba conectar a un SGDB de SQL Microsoft SQL Server 12.00.6433 desde un sistema con Ubuntu a través de un script PHP. (Los nombres
de servidor, usuario y password no son los reales.)

```php
    $servername = "host";
    $port="1433";
    $username = "usuario";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "";
    $connectionInfo = array("Database" => $dbname, "UID" => $username, "PWD" => $password);
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $connectionInfo);
    
    if ($conn) {
        echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
    } else {
        echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
```

```
El equipo tiene instaladas las siguientes versiones
```

> __Versión de **PHP** __
> PHP **7.4.3**-4ubuntu2.18 (cli) (built: Feb 23 2023 12:43:23) ( NTS )
> Copyright (c) The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v7.4.3-4ubuntu2.18, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
> __Versión de **Ubuntu** __
> No LSB modules are available.
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
> Release:        **20.04**
> Codename:       focal
> __Versión de **Apache** __
> Server version: Apache/**2.4.41** (Ubuntu)
> Server built:   2023-03-08T17:32:54
> __Versión de **OpenSSL** __
> OpenSSL **1.1.1f**  31 Mar 2020

Con DBeaver desde otro PC me conecto sin problemas con ese usuario y password.
Luego el servidor SQL Server está correcto.

Ejecutando el script de conexión php me da lo siguiente:

> Cnx_SQL$**php cnx_sql_server.php**

Conexión no se pudo establecer.

```
Array

    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 08001
                [SQLSTATE] => 08001
                [1] => 10054
                [code] => 10054
                [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746
                [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 08001
                [SQLSTATE] => 08001
                [1] => 10054
                [code] => 10054
                [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection
                [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection
            )
    
    )
```

Otra prueba que he realizado es lanzar el siguiente comando en Ubuntu:

> Cnx_SQL$ **sqlcmd -S *host*  -U *user***

Se recibe

> Password:

Así que entiendo que hay conexión entre ambos.  Diez segundos después muestra

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server : Login timeout
> expired. Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server : TCP
> Provider: Error code 0x2AF9.
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 18
> for SQL Server : A network-related  or instance-specific error has
> occurred while establishing a connection to 10.51.26.58MRD,1443.
> Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is
> correct and if SQL Server  is configured to allow remote connections.
> For more information see SQL Server Books Online..

> Cnx_SQL$ **php -i | grep sqlsrv**

```
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sqlsrv.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini
Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, ssh2.shell, ssh2.exec, ssh2.tunnel, ssh2.scp, ssh2.sftp, phar, sqlsrv, zip
PDO drivers => mysql, odbc, sqlsrv
pdo_sqlsrv
pdo_sqlsrv support => enabled
pdo_sqlsrv.client_buffer_max_kb_size => 10240 => 10240
pdo_sqlsrv.log_severity => 0 => 0
pdo_sqlsrv.report_additional_errors => 1 => 1
pdo_sqlsrv.set_locale_info => 2 => 2
sqlsrv
sqlsrv support** => enabled
sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize => 10240 => 10240
sqlsrv.LogSeverity => 0 => 0
sqlsrv.LogSubsystems => 0 => 0
sqlsrv.SetLocaleInfo => 2 => 2
sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors => On => On
```

Comprobación de módulos cargados en PHP

> Cnx_SQL$ **php -m | grep sql**

```
mysqli
mysqlnd
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlsrv
sqlsrv
```

Comprobación de paquetes ODBC instalados

> Cnx_SQL$ **dpkg -l msodbcsql17**

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-==========================================
ii  msodbcsql17    17.10.2.1-1  amd64        ODBC Driver for Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R)
$ dpkg -l msodbcsql18
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-==========================================
ii  msodbcsql18    18.2.1.1-1   amd64        ODBC Driver for Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R)
```

---

Otras pruebas
Conectando a un SGBD mysql en otro servidor desde el mismo equipo
no hay problema.

> $ mysql -u usermysql -h servidormysql.dom -p

```
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
mysql>
```

---

Para los requisitos previos se han ejecutado las siguientes ordenes

> if ! [[ "18.04 20.04 22.04" == *"$(lsb_release -rs)"* ]]; then
> echo "Ubuntu $(lsb_release -rs) is not currently supported.";
> exit; fi
>
> sudo su curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc |
> apt-key add -
>
> curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release
> -rs)/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
>
> exit
> sudo apt-get update  sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y
> **msodbcsql18**
> optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
> sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y **mssql-tools18**
> echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
>
> source ~/.bashrc
>
> sudo pecl install **sqlsrv-5.9.0**
> sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv-5.9.0
> sudo su
> printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" >
> /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
> printf ";priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" >
> /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
>
> sudo phpenmod -v 7.4 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
>
> sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Dinos qué version de OpenSSL tienes, ejecutando esto en la consola **`openssl version`**.

Comment: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
(Edite la pregunta para añadirla a la información)

Comment: Prueba a abrir el archivo `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` y cambia este valor, que suele encontrarse en la última línea: `CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2` por esto: **`CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1`** Luego guarda los cambios e intenta la conexión.